# Centered footer page numbers with apa6

Tags: titles, page-numbering, apa6

My university requires me to deviate from `apa6` format for thesis work, and make my page numbers centred in the footer (as opposed to top right).

I have seen some examples using `fancyhdr`, but can't seem to find something to match my case. I have been able to centre the page numbers everywhere except the title page. However, this also causes me to lose my running head in the subsequent pages.

I had a MWE, but lost it in cutting and pasting. So far, I have:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,apacite,natbib,noextraspace]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pslatex} %Times font
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\shorttitle{Shared Theories}

\title{Exceptional Thesis}
\author{Albert Einstein}
\affiliation{University of Unicorn}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\subsection{Something else}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: `apa6` uses `fancyhdr` already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apa6` defines `titlepage` and `otherpage` style with `fancyhdr` settings.

A redefinition just clears `\rhead{}` and sets `\cfoot{\thepage}`

The `\maketitle` uses the call `\pagestyle{titlepage}` then, so most likely both `titlepage` and `otherpage` have to be modified slightly and keeping the other settings as they are.

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,apacite,natbib,noextraspace]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pslatex} %Times font %REALLY????
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter

\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{%
  \rhead{}%
  \lhead{\rheadname: \MakeUppercase{\@shorttitle}}%
  \cfoot{\thepage}%
}


\fancypagestyle{otherpage}{%
  \rhead{}%
  \lhead{\MakeUppercase{\@shorttitle}}%
  \cfoot{\thepage}%
}
\makeatother

\shorttitle{Shared Theories}

\title{Exceptional Thesis}
\author{Albert Einstein}
\affiliation{University of Unicorn}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagestyle{otherpage}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\subsection{Something else}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Christian, the redefinition doesn't seem carry over to pages past the title page.

Comment: @V.Fast: According to my little example (which is basically yours) it does. All page numbers are centered in the footer.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for assistance so far. Please see my second MWE below. I didn't anticipate the footers and pagination to be dependent on having an abstract page.

Comment: @V.Fast: Well, you could have added that to your post above, not as an answer, but I'll take a look